# Return string/int from evaluated php code?

Tags: php, vbulletin

This is annoying me. In theory it should be easy but I don't live in theory.

Basically, I have an option to set a custom algorithm to make a 'code' that is either string or int.

This is user generated, and I then call that.

I have attempted to execute it using this code:

```
$code = eval('return($custalg);');
```

but that returns the actual algorithm entered, and not the value it would produce.

So my question is, how would I manage to execute the string in $custalg as php and then save the result into a variable?

Comment: Not an answer, but please please *please* reconsider your design. `eval()` is very bad in general, but with user supplied code it is an insta hack.

Comment: @PeeHaa The way it works, this would be on people's own server ;)

Comment: Ever heard of liability? If not I would suggest you look into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an echoed output with using the [PHP output control functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
eval("echo $custalg;");
$tmp = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$evalOutput = $tmp;
```

Or you just assign the return value to a global variable.

Comment: That has the exact same issue as described in question

Answer (score 4):

It looks you are not aware of difference between single quoted `'` and double quoted `"` strings in PHP. You should use:

```
$code = eval("return($custalg);");
```

if you want `$custalog` to be expanded:

> The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that
>   variable names will be expanded. See string parsing for details.

[See more in docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

So basically correct syntax depends on what `$custalg` is and where it is assigned. In your case I guess your `$custalg` is assigned in main code so you do not want substitution. Use code like this then:

```
$code = eval("return \$custalg;");
```

Comment: I didn't realise there was a difference. Now I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /pathtofile/login.php(119) : eval()'d code(57) : eval()'d code on line 1`. The second eval's code the the $code = one.

Comment: Edited answer produces same answer as question

Comment: it works fine for me (`$a = 'foo'; echo eval("return \$a;")` produces `foo` as expected). Ensure it is not other part of your code failing.

Comment: Not what I wanted, see selected answer

Comment: Sure, not a problem. But note it's not a best solution (even if it works), because if you are actually using output buffering for anything else then you got no buffer left and flushing it just for what you want may kill the purpose of using it in the first place.